# setup a LoaderMax function to return loaded data as an Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, gsap

In Flash, AS3, I can not make a re-usable function to work like this:

- I give it a file number (Number).
- It loads a TEXT file based on that Number (GreenSock loaderMax)
- When it was loaded, it split the loaded Data to an Array.
- And return back the ARRAY for me (after Data loaded).

This is my code so far:

```
package test.loaders{
    import com.greensock.loading.*;
    import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class LoaderTxt extends MovieClip {              
        private var _queue:LoaderMax;
        private var _textURL:String;
        private var _text:String;
        private var _Ar:Array = [];

        public function load(num:Number):Array{
            _txtURL = "data\text" + num + ".txt";

            _queue = new LoaderMax({name:"myLoader",onComplete:loadDone});          
            _queue.append(new DataLoader(_txtURL,{name:"thisTxt"}));
            _queue.load();

            trace("_Ar "+_Ar); //_Ar is empty

            return _Ar;
        }

        private function loadDone(event:LoaderEvent):void{
            _text = LoaderMax.getContent("thisTxt");
            _Ar = _text.split("\n");
            trace("_Ar "+_Ar); //This trace the loaded text correctly, as I like to return it.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it returns an empty Array, as it first return nothing, and then it loads the text.

for example:

```
trace (LoaderTxt.load("3"));  //empty
```

Any ideas please?

Regards,
  Ali

Answer (score 0):

Loading a file is an asynchronous action, meaning that `_Ar` will not be updated immediately after calling `_queue.load()`.

You can do one of two things:

1) add an event listener to your instance of `LoaderTxt` and re-dispatch the event in `loadDone`

2) pass in a "callback" function to your `load` method that will later get called in `loadDone`

Either way, you cannot get the results back immediately from `load()`